# Load a section content ( html & css ) from another page within the same domain but different folder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I need to load **example.com/shop/ #section** on the page **example.com/index.php**.
I am able to load the html using jquery but the css doesn't load, is it possible to do it with js without loading the stylesheets links from **example.com/shop/** in the head of **example.com/index.php**
Would using iframe be a better solution?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#box").load("/shop #section");
            });
     </script>
 
     <div id="box">
     </div>
```

Comment: you have to name file to be loaded ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I have tried also .load("/shop /index.php  #section");

Comment: You could type in the full address like www.example.com/shop/product.php #section